# What is the best way to configuring multiple proxy urls for multiple services in wiremock?

Tags: wiremock

I am using WireMock for service virtualization. I am using proxying functionality to forward all the unmatched requests to the live url. The problem is I am virtualizing 5 different services, how can I provide proxy urls for each service to forward it to corresponding live url in case of mismatch?

As of now I am using 5 different json files with proxyBaseUrl and high priority and setting them by default after starting the service. Is there any better way to configure multiple proxy urls for multiple services?

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPattern": "/a/.*"
  },
  "response": {
        "proxyBaseUrl" : "https://srvc1.com"
  },
  "priority": 10
}

{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPattern": "/b/.*"
  },
  "response": {
        "proxyBaseUrl" : "https://srvc2.com"
  },
  "priority": 10
}


{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPattern": "/e/.*"
  },
  "response": {
        "proxyBaseUrl" : "https://srvc5.com"
  },
  "priority": 10
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no support for importing multiple request/response pairs in the same json file.

Comment: Got it. As of now we are using different wiremock instances for different apps. Also, we are using the proxy-all argument to provide proxyUrl